# Overall (integration + unit tests) coverage on single file code view

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

I'm getting integration and unit tests coverage with sonarqube (v4.4). But the most important information is which parts of the code aren't covered by any of tests at all. I can easily get this information for whole projects on widgets, but on file view there is no option for overall coverage. Is this possible at all?

[I'm attaching a screen that possibly will explain my intentions better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZrF3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been added in 4.5, see https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5474

Comment: Will it give me possibility to browse code like with integration or unit tests coverage?                                             See link -> http://i.imgur.com/29CVIRs.png

Comment: Yep (or at least it should :))

Comment: Ok, I will upgrade sonar and try it out. Thanks.

Comment: For the record: it works, I've got overall coverage with v. 4.5.1 :)